# Get all the keys from json reponse - Python

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, key

My json data would look like this

```
{
   "a":1,
   "b":[
      {
         "c":2,
         "d":{
            "e":3
         },
         "f":{
            "g":4
         },
         "h":[
            {
               "i":5
            },
            {
               "j":6
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there a way I can extract all the keys from the response. What I would want is like:
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, it can. I see you have tagged this question with python. How far did you get? Do you have any errors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use recursive function and iterate over all items in dict.

```
def get_all_key(dct, lst):
    for k,v in dct.items():
        lst.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                get_all_key(d, lst)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            get_all_key(v, lst)

res = []
get_all_key(dct, res)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped me a lot. But I am also trying to get the value as well for each of the keys. Is this possible?

Comment: @JoxinJose, Do you know value of `b` is `list`, Do you want this `list`?

Comment: In this case, I require values for the following fields: a, c,e,g,i,j. Could this be done?

Comment: @JoxinJose, this is another question, please create a new one and ask another question.

Comment: I have posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487394/get-key-values-for-certain-fields-in-json-response

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it, using generators, for example:

```
def get_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield k
            yield from list(get_keys(v))
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for o in d:
            yield from list(get_keys(o))


print(list(get_keys(adict)))
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

---

If you want pairs (key, value) see this:

```
def get_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, (int, str)):
                yield (k, v)
            else:
                yield from list(get_keys(v))
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for o in d:
            yield from list(get_keys(o))

print(dict(get_keys(adict)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'e': 3, 'g': 4, 'i': 5, 'j': 6}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way I can get values for certain fields in the response along with their keys. So from this response, the fields for which I expect values are a, c,e,g,i,j along with the respective keys. Eg: [a:1,c:2,e:3,g:4,i:5,j:6]. Could this be done?

Comment: @Joxin I added an example

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer as this works, the other didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion (Depth-First Search) would be a go to for this:

```
def get_keys(data):
    keys = []
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            keys.append(key)
            keys += get_keys(value)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for value in data:
            keys += get_keys(value)
    return keys

print(get_keys(data=response))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above correct answers, this is also a method.

I mean there are a lot of ways in which we can do this, but they say smallest amount of work is the best work.

If all you data only string as keys and no key in the string, we can do this:

```py
import json
import re

json_text = json.dumps(a)
print([_.replace('"', "") for _ in re.findall(r"\"\w\"", json_text)])
```

Convert dictionary to json, find all the matching `"a"` where `a` is the character, then remove the `"` from all matches and voila..

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```